# Layers disappear, ArcGIS layout mode

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, layouts

The top two layers in my table of contents are the most important. Streams and some point shapefiles. They overlay a raster. In layout mode I switched from portrait to landscape. Immediately the streams thinned so much they are barely visible and the points are so small they are invisible. (I know they are there because they blink when I turn the layer off and on). Correct locations though.

There were two similar topics online. One suggested checking the size and position in the properties to make sure it isn't negative. Done. The other was to delete the border. Done.

Unfortunately neither worked.

I'm on ArcMap 10.1 if that helps.

Comment: Features in layout view typically tend to look more faded out than in data view at full layout extent.  For example, if the paper size in set to something like 36/42", lines and points that appear thick in data view will look thin and small in layout view.  Try clicking the zoom 1 to 1 button in the layout view toolbar to see if that shows the data like in the data view.

Comment: Ah thanks that worked. The size of the layout got changed and some of the features disappeared since they were too small. Everything exported fine and was editable in Illustrator so I just re-sized there.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above:

> Features in layout view typically tend to look more faded out than in
>   data view at full layout extent. For example, if the paper size is set
>   to something like 36/42", lines and points that appear thick in data
>   view will look thin and small in layout view. Try clicking the zoom 1
>   to 1 button in the layout view toolbar to see if that shows the data
>   like in the data view.

Answer (score 0):

there should be no need to resize the points and streams in a different software like illustrator. try this:

- rightclick your dataframe (called "layers" by default) in the table of content
- select properties
- go to general tab
- enter a reference scale (see image below)

[image: ref_scale]

adjust the size of the points and streams if needed. ArcMap will now scale all the elements in your TOC to fit the reference scale.